# Need wired/wireless atheros driver for AR9285 and AR8152

Tags: 10.10, kernel, wireless, 64-bit, ath5k

How can I install atheros drivers to my Toshiba laptop (64bit), manually?

I need AR9285 wireless adapter, and AR8152(v1.1) wired, fast ethernet.

I cannot connect my UberStudent1.0 (linux OS, Ubuntu10.04,equiv.) to the net. I have on the laptop Mint8 which connects well and able to download any drivers. Please, would you kindly show me how to install them if they are not .deb formats. Tarballs, zip,etc, still give me a hard time to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to install additional wireless drivers, this can be difficult without a network connection.

I recommend downloading the AMD64 .deb directly [from this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/amd64/linux-backports-modules-wireless-2.6.35-22-generic/2.6.35-22.12) and then copy them onto a USB key or CD-R and back onto your laptop. Then install it by double clicking on it and following the instructions in the Software Center, then you'll probably need to reboot. Your wireless card should work at that point.

After that install [linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic) so that you'll have that package installed so you'll get upgrades.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic
```

Comment: Man, you aaaaaaare(!) a gen1us! It worked perfectly in no time. Even though I had to burn the files into a dvd+rw because even the usb stick was not recognisable (i,e it had no drivers installed). You saved me lots of time. I have been trying this for days. You deserve a medal!  Thanks a lot again. God Bless you!

Comment: excuse me, but my software center doesn't seem to be able to download AMD64.deb
why is that? 
is there another way to download it?

Answer (score -1):

check [this](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) for wireless driver! I had the same problem before and I've found the solution!

 for install drivers you can simply go to **System > Administration > Additional Drivers**, ubuntu will detect drivers you need

Comment: This doesn't work with my laptop. That place is completely empty, even with my Mint8 which connects to the net.