# Need wired driver for an Atheros AR8152

Tags: 10.04, networking, drivers

I have bought a new Dell Inspiron N4010 laptop with Windows 7 installed. I have installed Ubuntu via Wubi. I am using a BSNL Broadband connection with a ZXDSL 831A11 modem.

Internet is working fine in Windows 7. But after logging into Ubuntu, I am not able to get an internet connection. There is no eth0 connection active. And my network card is : Atheros AR8152 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller

Some more info by googling : http://www.downloadatoz.com/driver/articles/download-atheros-ar8152-fast-ethernet-controller-driver-for-dell-laptops.html

Any way to obtain this driver for Ubuntu?

Comment: is your modem connected via USB oder viva LAN (RJ45) to the notebook?

Comment: Are you using network manager for connecting internet?Post the output of `ifconfig -a` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` in pastebin and give the link.

Comment: via LAN.. And my network card is : Atheros AR8152 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller..

Comment: @Karthick: yup.. i tried looking into ifconfig.. it just showed lo, it dint have eth0.. The same in the Network Manager..

Comment: Feels like this Ethernet card is not supported by Ubuntu..:-(

Comment: Manually add the following in your interfaces file..`sudo /etc/network/interfaces` auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
mtu 1500
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255

Comment: some more info by googling : http://www.downloadatoz.com/driver/articles/download-atheros-ar8152-fast-ethernet-controller-driver-for-dell-laptops.html.. Any way to obtain this driver for ubuntu..

Comment: @karthick: my ubuntu is minimal.. i have only one system.. and since i dont have internet in ubuntu, everytime i need to load windows and type these repliess.. so it is not possible to post the output in pastebin.. please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9449490, #6 likely solution steps. Dell 4010 Atheros wired ethernet driver not in kernel 10.04 64.

Comment: Dint work.. installation was success.. but network dint come up.. still ifconfig -a displays only lo..

Comment: on a second reboot it was working fine..

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess so please update your question if you try this and it doesn't work but it worked for [this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11015/need-wired-wireless-atheros-driver-for-ar9285-and-ar8152) with a similar card so maybe we'll get lucky and the updated wireless driver will pull in one for the NIC.

Install [linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

and then reboot and try it.

Comment: could not install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic.. Dependency issue..

Comment: @Sen Please add the error information to your question.